# how to use i18n module with hapi.js?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, hapi.js

I have read about the localization with i18n node module but it is given with node and express.js ,I am using hapi.s framework instead of express.js

I also read about the https://github.com/codeva/hapi-i18n but is not working.

Please help with this problem.

Comment: I hope this helps someone, have a look at [hapi-i18n](https://github.com/funktionswerk/hapi-i18n)

Answer (score 0):

[There is an example](https://github.com/efkan/node-intl-polyfill-example) that provides a simple `i18n` usage with plain JavaScript objects `{}`.

However, I add the request language with the following code. Then I use it on related route middleware by using `expressjs`.

You should use the code in accordance with `hapijs`

```
/* ADDING LOCALE and REGION INFO TO THE REQUEST OBJECT */
app.use(function (req,res,next) {
  // Finding the region of the request
  let acceptsLanguages = req.acceptsLanguages()
  let region
  let idx
  for (var i = 0; i < acceptsLanguages.length; i++) {
    idx = acceptsLanguages[i].indexOf('-')
    if (idx) {
      region = acceptsLanguages[i].substr(idx + 1, 2).toLowerCase()
      break
    }
  }
  // Choosing the default region as U.S.
  req.region = region || "us"
  // Choosing 'en-US' as default
  req.language = req.acceptsLanguages(appLocales) || 'en-US'
  next()
})
```

I hope this helps you.